# How to increase the speed of an animated texture?

Tags: animation, texturing, image, video-sequence-editor, keyframes

[image]Thanks for stopping by. Well, I am pretty new to blender and I don't really know much about it's functioning and all that stuff, but recently I came across animated textures. So I thought of creating a television in blender. I created the model, changed it's screen to emission type, added the video file that I wanted, checked the auto refresh tickbox, entered the max number of frames so that it doesn't stop halfway and then I hit spacebar.

Well, to be honest, I was disappointed with my work. During the fist 2 seconds, the animated texture was working fine. But then after that, it became slow and continued to remain that way. So I thought maybe the final product would be different. So I added a camera, did a quick keyframe animation to a cube beside it and then using image sequence, I rendered the pictures. Then I went to my file explorer and (because I am a bit lazy) opened the fist pic and held the arrow key (to create that flipbook effect you know)

Again, the results were same, the first two seconds, AHA buttery smooth, the very next moment, all slow like ice.

So, my question is where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: please provide your blend file...or a screenshot of your shader nodes

Comment: I've added the screenshot mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm so I figured it out anyways.

So the thing is, when you're putting an animated texture on, just render it in .FFMPEG format, it automatically adjusts it to its normal speed.

I wasn't using it before because I saw a video about its disadvantage, (I was using image sequence method to render out final animation) but the thing is, even if the files gets corrupt in between it doesn't affect the overall animation. Simply, just render it again (in case it happens)

That was all folks!

Seeya!